# When was the structure dereference with "->" intoduced in C?

Tags: c, struct, operators, dereference

I want to use the operator `->` in a recent project (written in C), but I constantly get the error `Illegal member reference for "->"`. I know that this operator can be used in the recent C and C++ versions. The C standart used by my compiler/linker is `C89/C90`, i think. Do you guys know in which update the structure dereference with `->` was introduced?

Comment: It's been in C since the very beginning; you are more likely to be trying to use it with a structure reference rather than a pointer.

Comment: Try to post your code...

Comment: Thanks, then i need to go through the compiler settings. Project compiled on an other machine just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has been in the language since its creation, far earlier than the C89/C90 ANSI/ISO standardization.

Your compiler error is most likely related to some mistake in your code and not to the language standard.